# How can I trigger this event in Jquery from my code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

I'd like to give this code conditions during the validation process of the form .. If the ESN list text field  input value is in the range of 1000 to 3000 , I'd like the drop down to automatically select STM3 below , if the range of the number input is between 5000 and 9000 , I'd like Trackpack  option from the drop down to automatically populate after a user  for example input 6000 on the text input field because it is between 5000 and 9000 ..

**Q:** How can I trigger the dropwn menu after typing a number on the text field  based on a condition , like ranges between numbers that will trigger one of the dropdown options from the select tag?

```
<html>
    <head> <title> Form </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(':submit').click(function(e) {
     $(':text').each(function() {
      if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <form id="provision">
    ESNList:    <input  type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" /> <br />
    ESN Start:<input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
    ESN End: <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
    UnitName:<input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30"  />  <br />  
     Unit Model:   <select name="STxName">
    <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
    <option value="protopak">Protopak</option>
    <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
    <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
    <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
    <option value="smartone">Trackpack</option>
    <option value="smartoneb" >SmartOneB</option>
    <option value="audi">Acutec</option>
    </select> <br />
    RTU Model Type:
     <select name="rtumodel">
    <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
    <option value="both">Both</option>
    <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
    <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
    </select> <br />
    <input type="submit" value ="submit"  />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You still have that typo in your script (`if($(this.val().length == 0)` should be `if($(this).val().length == 0)`)

Comment: @JeromyFrench Sorry I copied and pasted from the original code ..

Comment: You just had a question with this as the result code.  That means you made **NO attempt** to solve this on your own.

Comment: @Hogan, No I solved it .. This question is totally different . You haven't read it . The earlier issue was solved . I just copied and paste the same question for another subquestion that was not answered .. Jemery advised me to repost it for the other question I had , autopopulation of the dropdown menu ..

Comment: @PHP_lover - Exactly my point.  This is a different question which you did no work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the setInterval function.  I recommend you do some reading up on it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

In addition, you may find your solution here on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PCB5d/

Subsequently however here is the code:

```
function checkValues()
{
  ESNList = jQuery("#ESNList").val();
    jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");  
  if((ESNList >= 1000) && (ESNList <= 3000))
  {
    jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
  }
  if ((ESNList >= 5000) && (ESNList <= 9000))
  {
    jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
  }
  // you should be able to follow the above and add your own conditions  
}

function checkInput()
{
  jQuery(":text").each(function (){
    if (jQuery(this).val().length == 0)
    {
      jQuery(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
    }
    else
    {
      jQuery(this).css("border", "0");
    }
  });
}
setInterval(function () {checkInput();checkValues();}, 500);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: @Amd4632.. THANK YOU SO MUCH , words can't explain how grateful I am , but the thing is this , when I add this script in an HTML file altogether with the HTML code and I try to run the code , nothing happens ?  but it works from jsfiddle though .. I'll keep you posted . THANKS AGAIN :)

Comment: everything works fine Amd4632 .. Then once the dropdown menu autopopulates .. How can I actually make it work so the user can override the option that has been automatically populated while still leaving the autopopulate feature ????